# Using anchor links to redirect within email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, hyperlink

I am having trouble in linking to a specific area of webpage through the use of anchor links.

Example:  `<a href="http://www.example.com/page.html#myanchortag">`

Whenever I include the '#' it no longer redirects the page at all. The link is still 'clickable', but the page doesn't change.

Is this something that can be achieved that I am going about the wrong way, or is it not possible?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Example of formatted links:

[image]

Comment: Please can you elaborate? Can I confirm you are creating an email with a link to an anchored page? I've tested this and it's working correctly for me with [this anchor link](https://github.com/eliotharper/custom-activity-deskapi-node#pre-requisites) in an email. Are you using link tracking? When the page loads, is the `#myanchortag` still present in the URL or is it stripped?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eliot - when I paste the URL you provided into the a href of a link within an email, the link does not pass me through (its clickable but the page show no action being taken). If I remove the #pre-requisites, it carries through fine. I will paste a screenshot of how the links are formatted.

Answer (score 1):

The strange thing is that I'm unable to reproduce the issue you are experiencing. I'm using Classic Content, but perhaps you are using Content Builder? Anyway, here's what I would try.

Paste the following code into your email and determine if either of the following two links work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

%%[
    var @href, @hrefEncoded
    set @href = 'https://github.com/eliotharper/custom-activity-deskapi-node#pre-requisites'
    set @hrefEncoded = URLEncode(@href)
]%%


<p>Read the <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@href)=%%">pre-requisites</a>.</p>

<p>Read the <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@hrefEncoded)=%%">pre-requisites</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code - interestingly enough this is having the same behaviour. I just realized though, it will actually load if I right click -> open in new tab. Could it be browser specific? I am using Chrome on Mac - and the Classic Content within SFMC.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you were testing the links from email preview (which I assume you are doing). Have you tried sending yourself an email (e.g. a test send)?

Comment: D'oh - fooled by the Send Preview without using a real send. My mistake. I can confirm after doing a test send that it is working as expected. Thank you for the help on this one.